# LC_MESSAGES has no effect

Tags: linux, localization, linux-mint

Setting up LC_MESSAGES changes messages (in my case) from russia to english.

```
$ env | grep UTF
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=ru_UA.UTF-8

$ git status .
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 11 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Everythings seems OK, but connecting to this host via ssh. Make messages back to russia despite on variable LC_MESSAGES. Look:

```
$ ssh user@localhost
$ env | grep UTF
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=ru_UA.UTF-8
$ git status .
В ветке master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 11 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

нечего фиксировать, рабочая директория пуста
```

How to leave interface in russia but force messages to be in english?

> $ uname -a
>   Linux KES-PC 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What is the output of `locale` in both contexts?

Comment: @thatotherguy: difference is LANGUAGE=ru_UA:ru, in ssh it is setted up. It is setted up at /etc/default/locale, but who unset that env in first case (in my normal session)? http://superuser.com/questions/392439/lang-and-language-environment-variable-in-debian-based-systems

Comment: @thatotherguy: priority does not work `LANGUAGE=en:ru` or `LANGUAGE=ru:en` shows messages in russia in both cases. `LC_MESSAGES` is setted up to `en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @thatotherguy noted, I must use `locale` to see what is coming on.

in first case:

```
$locale
LANG=ru_UA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

after ssh

```
$ssh user@localhost
$locale
LANG=ru_UA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru_UA:ru
LC_CTYPE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The difference is `LANGUAGE`. googling help. That variable are setted up in `/etc/defaults/locale`

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="ru_UA:ru"
```

So I add to my `.bashrc`

```
export LANGUAGE=en
```

But now I do not understand:

1. I have `LANGUAGE` are setted up at /etc/defautls/locale. Why in first case its value empty string?
2. Why `LANGUAGE` priority does not work? If I set `LANGUAGE=en:ru` or `LANGUAGE=ru:en` I have russian messages in both cases.